# How to use same libraries on whole project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-build

I'm using many applications in one project like :

[image]

So i have some questions here, Application must implement iterated libraries ?

Assume i have `com.android.support:appcompat` in my "app" `gradle` and have the same one in my "opencv-java" `gradle` the apk will compiled with both libraries and double the size?

- If no, then what happened in compiling process?
- If yes, How i can avoid this, is there a way or some thing?

**Update** :

If i have libraries (e.g: "volley", "support" etc..) in my app "gradle" and also i used it in my open-cv "gradle", that's make me able to remove those libraries from **app** "gradle", it's seems that main app that used `compile project(':another-app')` in "gradle" can use **another-app** libraries, with codes and assets, every thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the apk will compiled with both libraries and double the size?

No.

> then what happened in compiling process?

Well, one of two things:

1. If you use `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"` consistently, Gradle will only use one copy of that dependency.
2. Your build could fail with an error message complaining about duplicate Java classes, stemming from the duplicate libraries. This would happen if you are not actually using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` in one place, but instead are adding `appcompat-v7` by some other means (e.g., directly compiling against a copy of that library project).

What *can't* happen is your double-the-size scenario, as you cannot have two copies of the same Java class in a single APK.

Comment: Why i can have same library in the same dependency? Why it's may throw error on start if  another gradle used the same library but with different version?

Comment: @Ibrahim: I am sorry, but I do not understand either of those questions.

Comment: @Ibrahim: "it's seems that main app that used compile project(':another-app') in "gradle" can use another-app libraries, with codes and assets, every thing" -- correct. These are called transitive dependencies.